# Can pseudo-rectangular equal-area map projection have equidistant parallels?

Tags: coordinate-system

Among the six pseudo-rectangular [Eckert projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eckert_projection), three are equal area and three have equally spaced latitudes.  The equal area maps have parallels spaced to preserve area, I wonder if the same can be achieved by changing the shape of the meridians.

Is it possible for an equal area pseudo-rectangular map projection to be both equal area and have equally spaced latitudes?

If yes, what are some examples of projections that share all three properties (equal area, pseudo-rectangular, equally spaced parallels)?

Comment: Sinusoidal is close to what you want I think, except maybe no cylindrical enough.

Comment: @mkennedy It's pseudocylindrical as long as all lines of latitude are straight parallel horizontal lines.

Comment: Yes, the sinusoidal projection is pseudocylindrical, equal area and the parallels are equally spaced, so it fits with your description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**sinusoidal projection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinusoidal_projection) satisfies your criteria of

- **equal area** – areas are true to scale
- **pseudo-rectangular**  – aka pseudo-cylindrical
- **equally spaced latitudes**

It also is **equidistant** in that scale along the equator and along all parallels of latitude are true to scale.

[image]

Note, however, that the equal-spacing of the parallels is not what makes it an equidistant projection (it is their lengths). The wording in your question suggests you may have conflated these.